# Is there a way to fire other plugin functions from wp_insert_post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating new post using  `wp_insert_post` inside function.php. All the posts are created fine. I use FS POSTER plugin to share published article on social automatically. When I created posts using  `wp_insert_post`,  FS POSTER does not share the post.
But when I create and publish post manually, it will share the post automatically.

How to notify other plugins like fs poster or any other social share plugins when I create the post using  `wp_insert_post`.

if I create post in function.php, with post status `draft` and then publish it using UI publish button, it will share automatically.

How to fix this, what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

the plugin you use probably does not listen to newly created `wp_insert_post` and its related hook, I can only guess it only runs if `wp_insert_post` is called to update a record.

The thing is when you create a post in admin panel there are multiple actions that runs and you are not creating a database record when you hit save. when you type in the Post Title, this automatically creates a record in posts table with `draft` `post_status`
and when you hit Save/Publish, you are actually updating the database record and not creating a new record that runs multiple action hooks.

On the other hand, `wp_insert_post` directly create a database record in a single action.

You can try something like setting the post status into a custom status,

i.e.

```
// Create a post, change the action hook or however you create the post
add_action('how-ever-you-invoke-post-creation', function() {
    $post = array(
        'post_title'        => 'My not so cool post',
        'post_type'         => 'post',
        'post_status'       => 'waiting'
    );
    $postID = wp_insert_post( $post );
});
```

the code above will create a posts record in your database and sets its `post_status` to `waiting`. just a note: you won't be able to see posts with custom `post_status` in admin dashboard

now, try publishing your post after its created using `wp_after_insert_post`

```
add_action('wp_after_insert_post', function( $postID, $post ) {

    if ( $post && $post->post_status === 'waiting') // only run if post status is waiting
        wp_publish_post( $post );

}, 10, 2);
```

If this still doesn't trigger your plugin related functionality, then they also did not listen for that `wp_publish_post` and all the related hooks that runs with it.

Your best bet would be to install query monitor and monitor the hooks that runs or dig in the plugin code yourself.